# Java Filter: Decode ServletRequest, process with decoded data, get and encode result and response user

Tags: java, spring, encryption, servlet-filters

I am creating a secure Java web application using Spring. For this I am using AES encryption to decrypt and encrypt request, response data.

I want to use filter for this functionality. **Here is the Flow:**

1. User request with encrypted data
2. Decrypt data in filter
3. Request controller with decrypted data
4. Get and encrypt response
5. Give encrypted response to requester.

I can decrypt request data and encrypt response. But I don't know how to send decrypted data to my controller. Please check attached image for more information.
[image]
**Thanks in advance!**

Comment: Why this all? HTTPS was already invented decades ago. Just let server do all the hard work.

Comment: afaik request approaches to dispatcher servlet after servlet filters do their job.

Comment: Can you please give me any reference link to do this work. I am little confused in this functionality.

Comment: @HemantSharma http://tutorials.jenkov.com/images/java-servlets/servlet-filters-1.png, DispatcherServlet is a type of servlet in this context.

Answer (score -1):

we create wrapper classes for request extends HttpServletRequestWrapper and response extends HttpServletResponseWrapper then create your encryption decryption logic class

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import javax.servlet.ServletInputStream;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper;

public class RequestWrapper extends HttpServletRequestWrapper {

    private final String body;

    public RequestWrapper(HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {
        super(request);

        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
        try {
            InputStream inputStream = request.getInputStream();
            if (inputStream != null) {
                bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
                char[] charBuffer = new char[128];
                int bytesRead = -1;
                while ((bytesRead = bufferedReader.read(charBuffer)) > 0) {
                    stringBuilder.append(charBuffer, 0, bytesRead);
                }
            } else {
                stringBuilder.append("");
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            throw ex;
        } finally {
            if (bufferedReader != null) {
                try {
                    bufferedReader.close();
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    throw ex;
                }
            }
        }
        String encryptData = stringBuilder.toString();
        String deCryptData = null;
        if (encryptData != null && !encryptData.isEmpty()) {
            deCryptData = DecryptEncryptData.decrypt(encryptData);
            if (deCryptData == null) {
                //Exception occured inside decrypt - Request Body not valid:
            }
        }
        body = deCryptData;
    }

    @Override
    public ServletInputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {
        final ByteArrayInputStream byteArrayInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(body.getBytes());
        ServletInputStream servletInputStream = new ServletInputStream() {
            public int read() throws IOException {
                return byteArrayInputStream.read();
            }

            public boolean isFinished() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return false;
            }

            public boolean isReady() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return false;
            }

            public void setReadListener() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        };
        return servletInputStream;
    }

    @Override
    public BufferedReader getReader() throws IOException {
        return new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.getInputStream()));
    }

    public String getBody() {
        return this.body;
    }
}
```

```
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletOutputStream;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponseWrapper;

public class ResponseWrapper extends HttpServletResponseWrapper {

    private ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    private PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(outputStream);
    
    public ResponseWrapper(HttpServletResponse response) {
        super(response);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public ServletOutputStream getOutputStream() throws IOException {

        return new ServletOutputStream() {
            @Override
            public void write(int b) throws IOException {
                outputStream.write(b);
            }

            @Override
            public void write(byte[] b) throws IOException {
                outputStream.write(b);
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    public PrintWriter getWriter() throws IOException {
        return writer;
    }

    @Override
    public void flushBuffer() throws IOException {
        if (writer != null) {
            writer.flush();
        } else if (outputStream != null) {
            outputStream.flush();
        }
    }

    public String getResponseData() {
        return outputStream.toString();
    }

}
```

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;

import javax.crypto.BadPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException;
import javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException;
import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class ApiFilter implements Filter{

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig arg0) throws ServletException {       
    }
    @Override
    public void destroy() {     
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;
        RequestWrapper requestWrapper = null;
        ResponseWrapper responseWrapper = null;
        try {
            requestWrapper = new RequestWrapper(httpServletRequest);
            responseWrapper = new ResponseWrapper(httpServletResponse);
            chain.doFilter(requestWrapper, responseWrapper);
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }  
        
        String responseData = responseWrapper.getResponseData();
        String encryptedResponseData = "";
        try {
            encryptedResponseData = DecryptEncryptData.encrypt(responseData);
        } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {

        } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {

        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {

        } catch (InvalidAlgorithmParameterException e) {

        } catch (BadPaddingException e) {

        } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {

        }
        OutputStream outputStream = httpServletResponse.getOutputStream();
        outputStream.write(encryptedResponseData.getBytes());
        outputStream.flush();
        outputStream.close();
    }

}
```

```
import java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.util.Base64;

import javax.crypto.BadPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException;
import javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

public class DecryptEncryptData {

    private final static String KEY = "";// provide your key
    private final static String IV = "";// provide your vector key
    private final static String algorithm = "";// provide your algorithm
    

    public static String encrypt(String plainText) throws NoSuchPaddingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException,
            InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, InvalidKeyException, BadPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException {

        SecretKey key = new SecretKeySpec(KEY.getBytes(), "AES");
        IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(IV.getBytes());
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(algorithm);
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, iv);
        byte[] cipherText = cipher.doFinal(plainText.getBytes());
        return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(cipherText);
    }

    public static String decrypt(String cipherText) throws NoSuchPaddingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException,
            InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, InvalidKeyException, BadPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException {

        SecretKey key = new SecretKeySpec(KEY.getBytes(), "AES");
        IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(IV.getBytes());
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(algorithm);
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, iv);
        byte[] plainText = cipher.doFinal(Base64.getDecoder().decode(cipherText));
        return new String(plainText);
    }

}
```

Comment: Please don't. Simply use HTTPS instead of HTTP.

Comment: This security over network only client to server... but in above code we create encrypt plain text request body from client side and send to server then on server our filter decrypt into plain text request body and pass same request to the controller